# Android Cuttlefish - Building the Docker image

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, android-build, android-kernel

I'm trying to build Android Cuttlefish based Docker containers and following the official guide here: https://github.com/google/android-cuttlefish/tree/main/docker

OS: `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` 
Command: `./build.sh --rebuild_debs_verbose` (from /docker loc of the repo)

In case of `root` use (via sudo or directly) getting following error:

```bash
Step 13/14 : RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash vsoc-01 -d /home/vsoc-01 -u $UID && passwd -d vsoc-01 && echo 'vsoc-01 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
 ---> Running in e55907df55bc
useradd: UID 0 is not unique
```

In case of a normal user with rootless docker:
I'm getting `cp` errors when it tries to copy files to `/home/vsoc-01` on the local host.

What I noticed that both of them should be done on the docker container but somehow the operations are done on the host, I'm mean `useradd` in case of the first and `cp` in case of the second.

you can replicate same results in a VM.
If would like to see more logs/details I'm happy to provide them, I really got stuck here

I tried Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04, Debian 10, Debian 11.
I tried with root, without root, with a new user, etc. nothing worked.

Comment: Please can you provide the error text of the `docker cp` errors?